# Implementing a command-line argument

Tags: c, command, character, command-line-arguments

I have to implement the main function with the following signature:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

What is a command-line argument and why don't I need test cases for it? And what do they mean by "signature"? Is it just the function prototype?

And I will definitely edit this question to include my attempt at the solution once I get these things clarified.

I'm confused on what this program essentially does, I can see it returns an integer value, but what does that integer value represent? Also, how would I return an integer value with the arguments specified in the argument list? What do they mean? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this homework or what?  That is the ubiquitous `main` entrypoint for just about every C application ever written.  You've asked a handful of questions here, *all of which* could be answered by using a search engine and doing a little research, or by consulting a basic C programming book.

Comment: I think what I'm most confused about is how to start the implementation file for this function. I've seen some extremely long examples and I've also seen some very short ones. I'm not completely sure how to start. :(

Comment: The implementation? What are you trying to do? `int main(int argc, char** argv)` is how **every** program starts!

Comment: Oh! I meant, I have to develop this in a file called: cmdline.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is a terrible question that shows little effort, I feel obligated to help ease your confusion.

Here's  a program which prints out it's name (`argv[0]`), and *requires* at least one argument.  If it isn't given at least one argument, it returns 1 to indicate failure.  Otherwise, it prints out its arguments and returns 0 to indicate success (to the shell, or whoever started it).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("Hello World, my name is \"%s\" \n", argv[0]);

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("I require at least 1 argument! Exiting!\n");
        return 1;  // Indicate failure.
    }


    printf("I was given %d command-line arguments:\n", argc-1);
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("  [%d] %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;    // Indicate success
}
```

Compile and run that program, things should become more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no programming experience whatsoever and I'll probably ask some stupid questions. :( But how did you know to put the "Hello World, my name is..."?

Comment: "how did you know to put" - Because it's my example program and I'm just making up whatever I feel like. That's how programming works.  And I started `i` at `1` because `argv[0]` is always the name of the running executable. The arguments start at `argv[1]`.

Comment: Seriously, don't be offended, but this isn't the place to learn how to program.  There are *hundreds* of sites out there that will teach you.  [Example](http://aelinik.free.fr/c/index.html). People aren't going to be willing to hold your hand through a bunch of "my first C program" questions.

Comment: Thank you for the link. And yeah, I understand. :) I'll try not to ask TOO many questions about basic stuff on here. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Work through some tutorials and develop a basic understand of a) how a program is compiled and run on the system, b) basic elements like loops and functions and structures, and c) how to do basic debugging (inserting print statements, using a debugger, etc.)  **Then**, come back and ask for help with the tricky problems. Welcome to programming!